# How to change disabled attribute of Kendo TimePicker?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I need some help with my mvc application.

I am using the following code to create a Kendo TimePicker.

```
@(Html.Kendo().TimePicker().Name("FirstShiftFrom" + prop.PropertyName.Substring(0, 3))
                           .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "workHoursTimePicker " + prop.PropertyName ,@disabled = "disabled" ,style="width:85px"})
```

How can I enable this control?

I have tried this in js :

```
document.get.Element.By.Id("id").disabled = false;
```

but it is not working!

Comment: FYI: please read the [doc](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/datetimepicker#methods-enable) sir..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using HTML **disabled** attribute to disable the Kendo Time picker use **Enable** method of Kendo Time picker widget.

e.g.

```
@(Html.Kendo().TimePicker().Name("FirstShiftFrom" + prop.PropertyName.Substring(0, 3))
                       .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "workHoursTimePicker " + prop.PropertyName, style = "width:85px" })
                       .Enable(false))
```

This will disable the Time picker and to enable it use this in javascript:

```
$("#TimePickerId").data("kendoTimePicker").enable(true);
```

Hope this helps!